# Как сделать так, чтобы голосовой ассистент читал файл правильно?

Tags: python, pycharm

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы мой голосовой ассистент читал файл, но он читает какие-то странные символы.

Вот код:

```
    print('Открываю файл')
    file_to_read = open('To read.txt', 'r')
    a = file_to_read.read()
    speak.Speak(a)
    file_to_read.close()
```

Ошибки python не выдаёт, но он читает что-то странное

Использую я модуль win32com.client

Comment: Если бы вы сделали вывод переменной а, и в вопросе указали что выводится, получили бы свой ответ намного быстрее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При открытии файла при помощи `open()`, нужно указывать кодировку. Например

```
open('To_read.txt', 'r', encoding="<кодировка>")
```

Но я бы вам посоветовал вместо open использовать `with`. Вот так:

```
with open(filename,'To_read.txt',encoding=encoding) as file_to_read:
  #do smth
```

Используя такую конструкцию вы менеевероятно совершите ошибку и ваш код станет более читаемым.

Comment: Кодировка скорее всего utf-8, но нужно смотреть конкретно для вашего файла.

Comment: Извините, я не понял, какую кодировку надо вставить в строке с with

Comment: Нужно выбрать ту кодировку, в которой закодирован ваш файл. Скорее всего это utf-8, но нужно смотреть в каком виде закодирован ваш файл при его сохранении (из текстового редактора). Так - же Если бы вы сделали вывод переменной а, и в вопросе указали что выводится, получили бы свой ответ намного быстрее.

Comment: Спасибо, скорее всего это заработало бы, но он выводит, что name 'utf' is not defined и подскажите, пожалуйста, как как проверить в каком виде закодирован мой файл при его сохранении?

Comment: [по поводу кодировки](https://support.socialkit.ru/knowledge-bases/4/articles/36371-faq-kak-proverit-kodirovku-v-tekstovom-fajle)

Comment: Спасибо, я уже разобрался как это делать